# Issue with Salesforce API version(Allowing to give wrong API version in package.xml)

Tags: apex, package.xml

I was doing one of the trailhead modules [Package.Xml](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/package-xml/package-xml-manifest)

and one of the steps to retrieve metadata from org. When I gave the wrong API version(60.0), I was able to extract the data from salesforce. Is this expected behavior?

[image: API Version 60.0]

[image: Result]

Comment: interesting, I guess it'll use the latest available, never tried this thing though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sourceApiVersion` on the [sfdx-project.json](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm) controls what API certain source CLI commands use.

> The sourceApiVersion determines the fields retrieved for each metadata
> type during source:push, source:pull, or source:convert.

I believe `package.xml` is not really a required file for a DX project structure (although it can help to simplify what you retrieve/deploy based on the listed components). Even for ([mdapi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_mdapi.htm)) commands, it seems **it uses the latest version supported by your CLI plug-in**.

> -a | --apiversion APIVERSION
> Optional
>
> **Use to override the default, which is the latest version supported by
> your CLI plug-in**, with the version in your package.xml file.

Hence, why you're seeing no issues setting the package.xml version to a non-existent version. It's just defaulting to whatever the CLI supports.

If you try to override the api version with the `- a` flag with the a wrong version (api version 99 is invalid until 2033).

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -x ./manifest/package.xml -a 99.0`

you'll get the following error

`UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION: Invalid Api version specified on URL`